# db2 sql select with only pure data

Tags: select, cron, db2

I am using a db2 here and I want to make some statistics about the table sizes over time.
My plan is to add a cronjob, which reads a specified table every 5 minutes.

For testing-purposes I use the command 
db2 "select (count) VALUENAME from TABLENAME where VALUENAME!=5"
which works fine.

Except the output, which looks like this:

```
VALUENAME
-----------
         15

1 record(s) selected.
```

I only want the value (15 in this case) to be written.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-x` option of the command line processor:

```
db2 -x "select whatever from wherever"
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you for reading.
I found a solution by myself: The export-function is doing exactly, wahat I want.
Now I have this row:

db2 "EXPORT TO filename OF DEL MODIFIED BY NOCHARDEL SELECT count (VALUENAME) from TABLENAME where VALUENAME!=5"

And than I work with that file.

Comment: Here, you are creating a file. Instead, the @mustaccio's answer is more accurate according to the answer.